# Getting data using Regular Expression in oracle

Tags: regex, database, oracle

I have data like

```
[A_B] A [1_@_312_AS] 232[232_A_@]AB_!@_12
```

What i want is

```
A 232AB_!@_12
```

I want to get data not in brackets with Regular Expression. I am using `REGEX_SUBSTR` function in Oracle DB

Can someone please help I am new to this field?

Comment: so, how have you used `regex_substr`?

Comment: my question was **how** have you used `regex_substr`? not have you used...so, what regex have you tried using?

Comment: ohh..sorry..i tried [^([*])]

Comment: how about `\[[^]]+\]`

Comment: @shyam - This will match everything in first bracket..

Comment: From what I see, if you remove all the text between `[]`s you get your desired output. Or, am I missing something

Comment: Yes..you are right!!..I want to get data not in brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    regexp_replace(t.mytext, '\[[^]]*\]', '')
FROM   
    (SELECT '[A_B] A [1_@_312_AS] 232[232_A_@]AB_!@_12' as mytext FROM DUAL) t
```

Regards,

AKDA

EDIT:
**regexp_replace** searches for param 2 (the pattern) in param 1 (the text) and replaces all instances with param 3 (empty string '')

The pattern matches an opening and closing bracket (\[ \]) surrounding an arbitrary number (*) of any character except a closing bracket ([^]])

Hope that explains it somehow... :)

Comment: It would be so kind of you if you will explain this.. :)